# How can I change this regular expression so grab the text before the FIRST colon and ignore the rest?

Tags: c#, regex

What do I have to change in this regular expression so that in both cases below it gets the text before the *first* colon as the "label" and *all the rest of the text* as the "text".

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TestRegex92343
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                //THIS WORKS:
                string line = "title: The Way We Were";
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<label>.+):\s*(?<text>.+)");
                Match match = regex.Match(line);
                Console.WriteLine("LABEL IS: {0}", match.Groups["label"]); //"title"
                Console.WriteLine("TEXT IS: {0}", match.Groups["text"]); //"The Way We Were"
            }

            {
                //THIS DOES NOT WORK:
                string line = "title: The Way We Were: A Study of Youth";
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<label>.+):\s*(?<text>.+)");
                Match match = regex.Match(line);

                Console.WriteLine("LABEL IS: {0}", match.Groups["label"]);
                //GETS "title: The Way We Were"
                //SHOULD GET: "title"

                Console.WriteLine("TEXT IS: {0}", match.Groups["text"]); 
                //GETS: "A Study of Youth"
                //SHOULD GET: "The Way We Were: A Study of Youth"
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know C# regex, but sounds like it is performing "eager". Do you have a flag for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new Regex(@"(?<label>[^:]+):\s*(?<text>.+)");
```

This simply replaces the dot with a `[^:]` character class.  This means any character except colon.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression are greedy, and the `.` matches *anything*. That's why label is getting the whole string. If your titles are always just text, I would recommend the following:

```
(?<label>\w+):\s*(?<text>.+)
```

Otherwise, you could make the expression not greedy with:

```
(?<label>.+?):\s*(?<text>.+)
```

You want to avoid the greedy operators whenever possible and always try to match specifically what you want.